# Finding the url for an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, image, selenium

I'm currently using a python web crawler to collect images searched on google. I used selenium to scroll down the searching page and used beautiful soup to record all the elements.

For some pictures, I can easily find the url without extra clicking, like "http://www.XXXXX.jpg". But for some pictures, if I don't click on it and just inspect the element, the src part would be like "data:image/jpeg;base 64,/...". And I will get the desired url by inspecting the zoomed image after clicking. But I don't know how to use selenium to click on the picture.

Are there any ways to get the urls for this kind of images?

Answer (score 0):

It could mean the image is encoded inside the `src` part of the html
to save the image you only have to get the long line of text after

```
data:image/jpeg;base 64,/
```

and decode it.

for instance

```
import base64
b64_data = "here_text"
imgdata = base64.b64decode(b64_data)
filename = 'some_image.jpg'  # I assume you have a way of picking unique filenames
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(imgdata)
```

it could also mean to run javascript after clicking a thumbnail, then to click the element all you have to do is

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".classname").click()
```

Comment: Now it maybe that that is only a thumbnail image stored as Base 64 string.  When you click on it there may be javascript happening in the background that is constructing the link on the fly to the actual image.

Comment: In that case you can click the element using Selenium

Comment: @mduiker Thank you guys! The click method really works. How could I construct a while loop or for loop to continuously click all the images? And once I clicked one image, all the elements of this image will be recorded, right? I know nothing about webpages...sorry.